# HP vp17 integrated speakers not working

Tags: windows-10, speakers

I have a new HP computer running Windows 10.  I connected an HP vp17 monitor with integrated speakers that won't work.  I have changed the audio cord and checked for updated drivers.  When external speakers are plugged into the audio on the pc, they work fine but not the speakers on the monitor. Any suggestions would be appreciated.